# How to fulfill and return a list from a method?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I'm trying to fill in a new list in `nearest` method. Basically, I do a comparison and add the nodes that agree with if case. I've already have a filled LinkedList with some values and I want to add some of them to a new list called nearList  in method and return it back.

```
public RankList nearest (Point p,double maxDist){
        RankList nearList = new RankList();
        Node current = first;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current);
            if((current.getPoi().location.dist(p))<maxDist){//Finding the distance between the added points with p argument
                nearList.insert(record); //Insert the distances shorter than maxDist in a new list.
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("null");
        return nearList;
    }
```

Calling the method from main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
RankList list1 = new RankList();
        list1.nearest(p,maxDist);
        list1.printList();
}
```

Printing the list method:

```
 public void printList() {
        Node current = first;
        System.out.print("HEAD -> ");
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current);
            System.out.print(" -> ");
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }
```

But it seems that none node is getting added to the list and I'm getting confused why.

Results:

```
HEAD -> null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `nearList.insert(record)`

The variable `record` is mentioned *nowhere* in this entire snippet. Presumably, it is a field in whatever class you're putting this method in. Three issues with that:

1. The design of the method appears to be such that it doesn't apply within the context of any class; it gets all the info it needs to operate via the parameters. Should it be, perhaps, static? At that point, your use of `record` would have been flagged as a compiler error (which is superior to 'I do not know why this does not work, I better ask SO').
2. The above sounds wrong; it sounds like `nearest` ought to be a message you send to a RankList; it should be a non-static method on RankList, maybe? It's hard to tell, the paste doesn't include enough context.
3. Don't use record, of course. I think you meant `current`.